# React-hook-form changes `undefined` to an empty string even on untouched fields

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a form and some default values, like this:

```
const defaultValues = {text: 'text'};
reset(defaultValues);
```

In the form, there are two text inputs with names `text` and `title`.

The problem is, the value of `title` is changing into the empty string on every change of form state:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const form = getValues();
    console.info(form, formState.touchedFields);
  }, [formState]);
```

Gives: `{text: 'text', title: ''}` and an empty object for `touchedFields`. This is quite critical since in the application there's a big difference between an undefined value and an empty string.

How can I make RHF not to change untouched values?

*edit*: take a look at this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-jang-d2s4n?file=/src/App.js

Comment: please can you include the enough code pointing to your issue  so we could accurately help

Comment: @AndeCaleb hm, I thought that this is enough. I'll try to reproduce it in some isolated place

Comment: @AndeCaleb I've added a codesandbox illustrating the issue

Comment: ooh ok. having a look

Answer (score 1):

So, as suggested here https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/discussions/7826 the solution is to use a controller:

```
const {
    formState: { errors },
    setValue
  } = useFormContext<T>();
const { field } = useController<T>({ name });
...
<YourInputComponent
value={field.value}
onChange={(e) => {
setValue(name, e.target.value, { shouldDirty: true, shouldValidate: true });
}}
...
```

Not an ideal way, but it works

Comment: i fixed it like that: `{...field} value={field.value ?? ''}`

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still having this problem and doesn't want to use a **Controller**, i have a better solution by setting `setValueAs` inside the **register** method options:

```
<input
  {...register('familyNumber', {
    setValueAs: (value) => value || undefined,
  })}
/>
```

For more information you can read the documention here: https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/register